# How to delete SSH keys

Tags: ssh, security, key-authentication

I am new to this field.

I had a server administrator but he left. I assume his key was installed in `authorized_keys`.

How to delete these keys if they exist. How can I find out if they are really  (still) installed there?

Comment: Your question needs a bit more focus, because it is quite unclear. As I understand it, you had one of your employees leaving. He had some keys in `authorized_keys`. That looks as if he had `ssh` access; is that so?  Is that on one, or in more than one server? With "What is the matter ..." , do you mean "how do I find out if those keys are present"? Please edit your question accordingly, do not just answer in the comments.

Comment: When entering the root and setting this command
cd /root/.ssh
Watch
authorized_keys
Would you have deleted the authorized_keys
Does it prevent me from entering the root?
Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new details.. Incorporate it so the question reads easily - not with "Edit" or "Update". Do not put extra information here in the comments as it can (and often does) get missed

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Are there other users that still need SSH remote access? If not you can safely remove the `authorized_keys` file for `root`. If yes you have to either find out which key belongs to whom and remove the correct lines or remove the file and re-create it with the keys of the users that are still authorized. Your admin might also have set up SSH keys for an unprivileged user (e.g. his name) which is allowed to use `su` or `sudo`. You can safely remove the files in the admin's personal home directory `~adminuser/.ssh`. But check the file for `root` as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about access specifically to root, you can log on to the server and look for the key in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If you know the key, you can take a part of the key string (somewhere in the middle, take a part without `/`) and use `grep` to see if it is there:

```
grep 'kSBgw8h0gM9IBV3OK9Bv9m1U3' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This will show you whether the key is present in root's `authorized_keys`. Instead of the kSB... , use of course a part of the previous employee's key.

If you want to check all `authorized_keys` files on your system, you can (as root) do:

```
find /root /home -name authorized_keys | xargs grep 'UckSBgw8h0gM9IBV'
```

To remove the key, you can remove the line with any editor, for example `nano`. Or from the command line:

```
sed -i '/Q6pym8osmWlnpZNYi11uW/d' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Thank you. I don’t want any remote access keys. If I permanently delete the authorized_keys are there server problems?

Comment: If you remove the complete `authorized_keys` file, then all the other keys that are allowed are revoked as well.

Comment: Thank you
You have opened the authorized_keys file. I found it empty and nothing in it
Are there other keys in another file?

Comment: Any user may have such a file in `/home/<username>/.ssh/`. If he may promote himself to root from a user account, that would be another entry point.

Comment: From the question on how to delete keys, the question now becomes "what must be done if a user/sysadmin leaves". There are many (incomplete, I must say) lists available, but it depends very much on your situation. Disable the accounts. Check all the `authorized_keys` files (not just root). Check `/etc/sudoers`. Reset the root-password. Check the contabs, clear the at-queues, backup and remove his personal files.  If he left with a grudge, check for rootkits.  etcetera etcetera.

Comment: home / <username> /.ssh/
  Inside this .ssh folder
There are no other key files
And this path I searched and found nothing
And I implemented this order
grep 0: 0 / etc / passwd
I did not find any other user
Am I perfect